# How is the option --define used in arangoimport?

Tags: arangodb

In the [documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangoimport-options.html), is it not clear how can I use this option?

Is it for telling arangoimport : "Hey, please use this field as _from/_to field when you import" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `define` `string…` Define key=value for a @key@ entry in config file

This has nothing to do with data import. `arangod`, `arangosh` etc. all support `--define` to set environment variables, which can be used in configuration files using placeholders like `@FOO@` and be set like `--define FOO=something` on the command line.

This is briefly explained here: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/administration-configuration.html#environment-variables-as-parameters

Example configuration file *example.conf*:

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:@PORT@
```

Example invocation:

```
arangosh --config example.conf --define PORT=8529
```

---

For delimited source files (CSV, TSV) you can use the option `--translate` to map columns to different attributes, e.g. `--translate "child=_from" --translate "parent=_to"`.

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangoimport-examples-csv.html#attribute-name-translation

If the references are just keys, then you may use `--from-collection-prefix` and `to-collection-prefix` to prepend the collection name.

`--translate` is not supported for JSON inputs. You can do the translation and import using a driver, or edit the source file somehow, or import into a collection and then use AQL to adjust the fields.